# Wrong call/caller graph with Doxygen and GraphViz in C++

Tags: c++, doxygen, graphviz

So I started to document a C++ project with Doxygen 1.8.13 (Windows 10, 64-bit) and encountered a problem with GraphViz's call/caller graph generation.

If a generate a documentation with the following code, Doxygen will generate a call graph that looks like:

[image: call graph]

But as the code shows, Path() doesn't call any function (empty body).

```
struct Path {
  Path(const Node* source_node, const Node* target_node, 
       const unsigned long cost, const std::vector<const Node*> path)
      : source_node(source_node), target_node(target_node), 
      cost(cost), path(path), length(path.size()) { };

  void printCompletePath(std::ostream& = std::cout) const;

  const Node* source_node = nullptr;
  const Node* target_node = nullptr;
  const unsigned long cost = 0;
  const std::vector<const Node*> path{};
  const std::vector<const Node*>::size_type length = 0;
};
```

But if I reorderd the code as follows, the call graph disappears (as intended):

```
struct Path {
  Path(const Node* source_node, const Node* target_node, 
       const unsigned long cost, const std::vector<const Node*> path)
      : source_node(source_node), target_node(target_node), 
      cost(cost), path(path), length(path.size()) { };

  const Node* source_node = nullptr;
  const Node* target_node = nullptr;
  const unsigned long cost = 0;
  const std::vector<const Node*> path{};
  const std::vector<const Node*>::size_type length = 0;

  void printCompletePath(std::ostream& = std::cout) const;
};
```

So is that a Doxygen and/or GraphViz bug? Or am I missing something?
(I don't wanna reorder my source code just for Doxygen to work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With version 1.8.13 I could reproduce the problem regarding the call graph. With version 1.8.14 this wrong call graph is gone.

From the doxygen change log: Function declaration following a function definition incorrectly listed as calling dependencing [ https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/436fc7ed1158d517dd6f6d25aa3e05568f8c3d94 ]

Comment: thanks for the answer (your link is broken because of the last "]")

Comment: Thank you, I ran into the same problem, after following the instructions on http://www.doxygen.org/download.html to install 18.14 resolved the situation;

Noteworthily; this also alerted me to the fact Doxygen (currently) does make mistakes sometimes, which is good to keep in mind. (e.g. if you have a member on a class called 'first' and then in a member method define a local called 'first', it will be seen as a call to the member rather than the local, when accessing a member on the local which also exists on the member, even this is not lexically the case.)

Comment: @Joeppie If the mentioned problem is an issue please post an issue in the doxygen issue tracer (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new) or post a question on stackoverfoow.

Comment: Hi Albert, I will try to find the time in my work routine to make a proper report for it, yes, thanks :)